# NHtmlUnit cannot submit button

Tags: submit, nhtmlunit

I'm discovering about NHtmlUnit to build an application web. But when I try it with auto login to yahoo mail. But after I run code. I refresh the login page of Yahoo so nothing changed. Not logged.

Code:

```
        NHtmlUnit.WebClient driver = new NHtmlUnit.WebClient();

        driver.Options.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        driver.Options.ThrowExceptionOnScriptError = false;
        driver.Options.ActiveXNative = true;
        driver.Options.CssEnabled = true;

        HtmlPage page = driver.GetHtmlPage("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?");

        HtmlForm form = page.GetFormByName("login_form");
        HtmlTextInput user = (HtmlTextInput)form.GetInputByName("login");
        HtmlPasswordInput pass = (HtmlPasswordInput)form.GetInputByName("passwd");

        user.SetValueAttribute("my account");
        pass.SetValueAttribute("my pass");

        HtmlSubmitInput submitButton = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.GetElementByName(".save");

        HtmlPage nextpage = (HtmlPage)submitButton.Click();
```

Please help me why. I write it on .NET MVC 4 C#. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Only update below single line,due to which u may face class cast exception

```
HtmlButton submitButton = (HtmlButton)page.GetElementByName(".save");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I had follow you but nothing change after I run code, I open new tab on browser and type link Mail.yahoo.com it still not logged.

Comment: Sry I can't understand.you mean to say that with the above code you are not able to login?

Comment: Yes brother. I want to build a tool for auto login or submit register form. And with code above a not able to login.

Comment: @user3156500 what issue you are facing now ? Before you was facing class cast exception

Answer (score 0):

**The code is completely fine, and should works.**

Probably the reason you think it is not, is that you check it by a wrong method!
One essential elements which makes a site (i.e. login.yahoo.com) see you as logged in user, is the cookies it provide to your browser/webdriver when you use login forms, so if you use the login procedure by an instance of `NHtmlUnit.Webclient` (i.e. `driver`) then you are only logged in inside the `driver` web client, not inside any other browser or client, even on the same machine.

> I tried to add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputations.